# How to use "Object" as model name in ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I love those simple words such as "Object", "Property", "Value" and would like to use them as Class Names, but seems they are reserved. ( ? )  ROR failed on many things with a model named "Object"

Make a prefix doesn't look good, such as CCObject, CCProperty.

Is there a way to allow me to use those simple words directly?

What I want to do is a universe program, domain objects are generated at runtime, which means usually classes like Product, ProductType, Article, or Author are all datas in database, not an actually Ruby class.

Comment: No matter how many times you ask, the answer is no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Object" is a vey generic sort of word. Even if it WERE possible to create a class with that name, I'd be very suspicious of the need to do it.

Is there something that you could prefix it with that would let imply some context? For a dental office application, maybe "DentalOfficeObject". Is that what the "CC" prefix is for, or is it arbitrary to make the interpreter stop complaining?

Comment: What I want to do is a universe program, domain objects are generated at runtime, which means usually classes like Product, ProductType, Article, or Author are all datas in database, not an actually Ruby class.

Comment: How about naming the class "UniversalObject"?

Answer (score 8):

How about not.  Just don't do it.  Even if it is possible, it's the easiest way to make your code completely unreadable and unmaintainable.

Answer (score 2):

"Object" is already the name of a class in Ruby. It's the root class of everything in the language. That's why it appears to be "reserved" — because it's already taken.

Comment: Is there any namespace thing we can do so I can use Object as a model name of ActionModel?

Answer (score 1):

My best bet would be Objekt, but still the name is adequate only if you're modelling an object model, which is silly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use them as Class names.. They are integral to ruby.